# How to ensure a .pcap file did not modified?

Tags: wireshark, pcap, packet-capture, wireshark-dissector

let say my friend send me a .pcap file capture by his computer Wireshark, and I know there had some software can modify this pcap file.(Such as EditCap)

How can I ensure the file had not modify by those software?
(I would like to ensure the pcap file must be original create by Wireshark)

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The pcap format has no built-in verification or validation that cannot be trivially spoofed.